# Deriving the derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have the following expression:

$$ \frac{W\left(\frac{p}{1-\gamma\Delta}\right) - W(p)}{\Delta}$$

and want to find out what happens as $\Delta \to 0$. I reformulate as

$$ W\left(\frac{p}{1-\gamma\Delta}\right) - W(p) \\
=  W\left(p - p + \frac{p}{1-\gamma\Delta}\right) - W(p)  \\
 = W\left(\frac{-p(1-\gamma\Delta)}{1 - \gamma\Delta} +  \frac{p}{1-\gamma\Delta} + p\right) - W(p)  \\
 = W\left(\frac{\gamma\Delta p}{1 - \gamma\Delta} + p\right) - W(p) 
$$

and then

$$\lim_{\Delta\to 0}\frac{W\left(\Delta \frac{\gamma p}{1-\gamma\Delta}+p\right)-W(p)}{\Delta}=W'(p)\gamma p$$

Is this correct? The last step is mostly intuition, and I'd be happy if someone could provide some more foundation here.

Comment: The last step is wrong. By continuity, your limit should be zero.

Comment: @JackyChong Yes, but I'm not sure how I'd prove the last step -- as I said in the question, it's more intuitive than anything else..

Comment: Just Taylor expansion or mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Another way to get your answer: Let $f(\Delta) := \frac p{1-\gamma \Delta} $. Then $f(0)=p,$ and so your fraction is
$$ \frac { W(\frac p{1-\gamma \Delta}) - W(p) }{\Delta} = \frac{W(f(\Delta)) - W(f(0))}{\Delta},  $$ 
and we recognize a difference quotient for $W\circ f$. By chain rule,

$$ \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{W(f(\Delta)) - W(f(0))}{\Delta} =  (W\circ f)'(0) = W'(f(0)) f'(0) =W'(p)\gamma p.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{W\left(\frac{p}{1-\gamma\Delta}\right)-W(p)}{\Delta}$$

Your calculation is correct.

But it is not necessary to transform the numerator of your expression. It is obvious that

$$\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0}\left(W\left(\frac{p}{1-\gamma\Delta}\right)-W(p)\right)=0.$$

So you have an expression $\frac{0}{0}.$

Apply simply L'Hôpital's rule for $\frac{0}{0}$: If $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g'(x)$ exist, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g'(x)}$.

$$\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{W\left(\frac{p}{1-\gamma\Delta}\right)-W(p)}{\Delta}=\frac{\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0}W'(\frac{p}{1-\gamma\Delta})p\gamma}{\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0}(1+\gamma\Delta)^2}$$

$$=W'(p)\gamma p$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed elaboration, but there was a typo in my original equations that I fixed. Sorry for the mess...